# How to return back when the button is clicked?

Tags: c, microcontroller

When I first press the button, it performs the first function, on the second press, it performs the second task when the third press I want to return and perform the same first function.

```
void blinkcursor(void);
int count = 0;

void blinkcursor(void)
{   
  label:
    if (button == 1) {                 //button pressed
        if (count == 0) {
            count++;
            set_cursor_position (1, 2);
            lcd_cout(0x0f);                      //cursor blink
            button = 0;
        }
        else if(count == 1) {
            lcd_cout(0x0c);                       //blink off
            button = 0;
        }
        goto label;
    } 
}
```

Comment: goto is bad usage.  avoid it.   just toggle the value back and forth between 1 and 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say much about the overall structure of your program, so I am just going to assume that you have some main loop running that regularly checks the state of the button, performs any necessary debouncing, and sets `button` to 1 whenever it detects that the button was pressed.  I will also assume that the cursor is not blinking by default, and that the button is *only* used to toggle the blinking of the cursor.

Now just add a call to the following function in your main loop:

```c
bool blink_enabled = false;

void update_blink(void)
{
  if (button) {
    // Button was pressed.
    if (blink_enabled) {
      // Turn off blinking.
      lcd_cout(0x0c);
      blink_enabled = false;
    }
    else {
      // Turn on blinking.
      set_cursor_position(1, 2);
      lcd_cout(0x0f);
      blink_enabled = true;
    }
    button = 0;
  } 
}
```

(You might need to add `#include <stdbool.h>` at the top to get the bool type.)